# Is it possible to tell if an interactive user session was started automatically vs. user's manual login?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc, terminal-services

Is it possible to tell if an interactive user session was started automatically vs. user's manual login?

I need to know this distinction from a Windows local service written in C++/MFC.

**EDIT:** By "automatically" I mean the first user account that is created after installation of Windows that does not have a password. In that case Windows automatically loads up into that account after boot.

Comment: Define "started automatically"

Comment: The only difference between the two types of logon is where the GUI logon process got the username and password from, so I think it unlikely that there is any reliable way to tell the difference.  I think the closest you could get is to look to see whether automatic logon is configured, and if it is and the username is the same, asssume the logon was automated.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan & others. Sorry, I was off. By "automatically" I mean the first user account that is created after installation of Windows that does not have a password. In that case Windows automatically loads up into that account after boot.

Comment: @c00000fd, in that case what's the value of `AutoAdminLogon`, `DefaultUserName`, and `DefaultDomainName`? i.e. does it use those values, or are they irrelevant to the initial logon after installation?

Answer (score 1):

Windows does not have "started automatically" types of login.
The type of login are one of `SECURITY_LOGON_TYPE` enum values. It is
defined in `<Ntsecapi.h>` like that:

```
typedef enum _SECURITY_LOGON_TYPE { 
  Interactive              = 2,
  Network,
  Batch,
  Service,
  Proxy,
  Unlock,
  NetworkCleartext,
  NewCredentials,
  RemoteInteractive,
  CachedInteractive,
  CachedRemoteInteractive,
  CachedUnlock
} SECURITY_LOGON_TYPE, *PSECURITY_LOGON_TYPE;
```

You can get the value using `LsaEnumerateLogonSessions` and
then `LsaGetLogonSessionData` and there it is as `sessionData.LogonType`.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. In my case both sessions would return `Interactive`